# AS400-CRTCMD Localization. Is it possible to change language at run time?

Tags: localization, ibm-midrange

I am actually converting all DDS files to use MSGID instead of plain text. I can now change the display language of the application just by choosing the right library with the MSGF in French, English, ...

But for the commands, it seems that CRTCMD needs a language file at compile time (with PMTFILE) and uses theses strings to generate the command. I could eventually delete the MSGF but the command will display the texts.

What I want to achieve is using the same *CMD object and be able to change the language when needed at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: assuming a currently supported release, 6.1 or higher...

I think you want to use *DYNAMIC on the `CRTCMD PMTFILE()` parameter

> *DYNAMIC
>       When the command is prompted, prompt text messages
>       will be dynamically retrieved from the message file
>       specified for this parameter using the message
>       identifiers stored in the *CMD object when the command
>       was created.  The message identifier specified for the
>       PROMPT or CHOICE parameter on a CMD, PARM, QUAL, or
>       ELEM command definition statement must be found in the prompt text
>       message file when the command is being     prompted.

So something like

```
CRTCMD CMD(MYLIB/MYCMD) PGM(MYLIB/MYPGM) SRCFILE(MYLIB/QCMDSRC)
 SRCMBR(MYCMD) PMTFILE(*LIBL/MYMSGF *DYNAMIC)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for the answer. We're still on V5R4 (migration to V7 planned   before end 2016). I think *DYNAMIC is not yet supported by V5R4, so I'll just wait for V7 to retry.
Sorry, I should have mentioned it in my first request.
If you mind adding info for the minimum OS version required to the answer, that will help other users.

Comment: @DotMG, looks like it was added at 6.1